# $G$ is a finite group and $T$ an automorphism of $G$ such that $T$ sends more than $\frac{3}{4}|G|$ elements to their inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a finite group and $T$ an automorphism of $G$ such that $T$
>   sends more than $\frac{3}{4}|G|$ elements to their inverse. Then we have show that $$T_x=x^{-1}$$ for all $ x \in G$ and $G$ is abelian.

I construct $ S= \{  x \in G : T_x=x^{ -1}  \}$ and for $ b \in G $, $ S_b= \{ xb:x\in S \}$ then $| S \cup S_b|\geq (1/2)|G|$. Let $ a \in S\cap S_b $ then $ a=tb $ for some $t\in S $. I dont know how to solve it by this construction or any other method. Give me any kind of help.