# Automorphism on finite group taking more than $3/4th $ elements going to inverse then G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I know this question is already answered but My argument is different I wanted t check that is I am giving right arrgument?

Let G be the group and T is automorphism which send more than $3/4th$ elements goes to there inverse then G is abelian.
Claim:$T(x)=x^{-1} \forall x\in G$
Let S={$x\in G|T(x)=x^{-1}$}
|S|$\geq 3/4|G|$      ......Given

Case 1: If S is subgroup 
 
Then by Lagrange theorem |S| divides |G| 
As |S|$\geq 3/4|G|$  
then  S=G  Hence We are Done

Case 2: If S is not a subgroup.
As $T(e)=e$ For any automorphism T Hence
$e \in S$ 
Consider $x\in S$ then $T(x)=x^{-1}$ 
 $T(x^{-1})=x\in S$
 Hence $x^{-1} \in S$ That is for every $x\in S$ $x^{-1} \in S$ 
 As S is not subgroup as assumed Therefore It must not satisfy closure.

Define $a^{-1}S$={$a^{-1}x|\forall x \in S$}
There exist some $ a \in S $ such that $a^{-1}S \neq S$ as Closure of elements of S has not been Guarrented.
$a^{-1}S \neq S$
 So there is some $t\notin S$ but $ t\in a^{-1}S$ 
$t=a^{-1}x $ for some$ x \in S$ Therefore $at=x$ 
i.e $at\in S$
 So $T(at)=t^{-1}a^{-1}$=$T(t)T(a)=$$T(ta)$ 
This is true for any $t\in a^{-1}S$ 
For all $t\in a^{-1}x $ $ta=at$
$t \in N(a)$ and for any $t \in a^{-1}S$ this is true.
 there for  $a^{-1}S \subset N(a)$
We can show bijection between S and $a^{-1}S$ so Cardinality of both are same
 $|a^{-1}S|=|S| \geq 3/4||G|$ 
 And N(a) is subgroup
 $N(a)=G$. i.e $a \in Z(G)$ 
That means every $a \in S ,a \in Z(G)$ This implies $S=Z(G)$ which is subgroup 
which is contradiction to our assumption Hence Done . 
S is Subgroup S=G 
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Your proof looks correct mathematically but your presentation could use some work.

Comment: It is very hard to read. Just try to use the point at the many right points. The idea of proof is not transparent. "This is true for any $t$..." is unclear. What is "This"? Why not state the corresponding property first. The inclusion $a^{-1}S\subset N(a)$ is unclear, and it is **very unfortunate** to have this written without point and new sentence. How should people digest $$ a^{-1}S \subset N(a)\ |a^{-1}S|=|S| \geq 3/4||G\ ?$$

Comment: @dan_fulea Sorry Sir For My Mistake .I had edited question so now it become quite readable.Please Suggest me my mistake .Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It is still useful, I think, if you compare your proof with the proofs given at the [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487142/g-is-a-finite-group-and-t-an-automorphism-of-g-such-that-t-sends-more-th?rq=1), where several people put real effort to explain it.